# Get html file from project resource, fill placeholders and convert it to w3c document

Tags: java

I have a simple html file like this

```
  <td style="width: 59.4824%; height: 28px;" data-mce-style="width: 59.4824%; height: 28px;"><span
                style="font-size: 18pt;" data-mce-style="font-size: 18pt;">Boss <span
                style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;">{boss.name}</span></span>
        </td>
```

that placed in spring boot project folder resources

i need to get it from it, replace {boss.name} with java object boss.getName() and convert it to w3c Document

what is the best way to do these steps?

ps.It is print form that will be convert to pdf file after these steps